# HSQL DB size if huge after we implemented delete operations on large dataset

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

So we are working on a large dataset that will store 2-3 million records in the HSQL table and delete after every few minutes once a certain limit is reached, we observed that once we implemented this delete functionality the size of the database has increased from 450MB to 5GB approximately on the same dataset, is it possible that HSQL stores these deleted data for some time in the database? or maintain multiple copies? if so how to avoid it, once we delete the data we want the data to be removed from the database and reclaim the space. Is there any setting available? Our goal is to use as less disk space as possible. We will be working with only 1 connection to the database, so we don't need thread safety or MVCC and we are okay with occasional data corruption or data loss when the instance goes down, we also run all the connections with auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 1):

With older versions of HSQLDB you needed to execute the SQL statement `CHECKPOINT DEFRAG` in order to reclaim the space for deleted rows.

With the latest version 2.6.1 and later, there is a a new setting to manage the space reuse. You need to execute `SET FILES SPACE TRUE`. Then for each large table, you execute `SET TABLE <tablename> NEW SPACE`. Finally, execute `CHECKPOINT DEFRAG`. The space left from deleted rows is then reused automatically. See the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#tspace_usage

If you are deleting ALL the rows in a table, you can instead execute `TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename> AND COMMIT` as a faster alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much Fredt, but if we are executing CHECKPOINT DEFRAG then it will create back up files right? We dont want back files and we run db with log file as false.

Comment: You do not need to do CHECKPOINT DEFRAG if you enable the space reuse.

Comment: we are using version 2.5.0, so is there any other way to reclaim disk space other than executing CHECKPOINT DEFRAG? given that we don't want to create backup files and use as less disk space as possible

Comment: table spaces are supported in version 2.5.0